# Float divisions returning wierd results

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

Im trying to do a project and for some reason the same divisions give me different results. I am trying to check if 2 divisions are equal and give me the same results but When I try `5.99/1` and `0.599/0.1` the script says that they are different while they are supposed to return the same results. I figured out what the problem is that `5.99/1 = 5.99` and `0.599/0.1 = 5.989999999999999`but I cant find a fix for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: It doest answer my question on why this happens but I cant seem to find a fix for python.

Comment: Does it or doesn't it? You wrote "doest", which is halfway between does and doesn't :) Read the answers there carefully. The accepted answer contains a workaround for equality checks with floating point numbers. There is no _fix_ for this because it's an intrinsic problem with floating-point binary numbers. There are links in the answers to further information. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is pretty comprehensive

Comment: there's no way to fix except using a decimal floating-point type

Comment: For good alternatives, it is useful to see your true code.  Consider posting a [mcve] to improve this question.

Comment: "When I try 5.99/1 and 0.599/0.1 the script says that they are different"   --> Because `5.99, 5.999, 0.1` do not encode exactly as floating point numbers.  Perhaps tolerate a small difference in the two quotients?  Is that allowed?

Comment: its doesnt and by fix i meant a way to make my code work and round() function worked

Answer (score 0):

You can find the reason in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/11502612

I have written a possible solution for you:

**Code:**

```
a = 5.99 / 1
b = 0.599 / 0.1
a_str = "{:.4f}".format(5.99 / 1)
b_str = "{:.4f}".format(0.599 / 0.1)

print(a, b)
print(a_str, b_str)
print(a == b)
print(a_str == b_str)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
5.99 5.989999999999999
5.9900 5.9900
False
True
```

As you can see below I have converted the result of division to a formatted string and I check them instead of default floating type.

Comment: It's cheaper to do `abs(a - b) < 1e-4`, which is what the linked duplicate's accepted answer suggests. Please don't answer duplicate questions. Instead, flag / vote to close them.